# How can I combine two `sf` geometry fields into a single geometry field (of type GeometryCollection)?

Tags: r, geometry, r-sf

I have two spatial descriptors for the same real world objects (we can simply call them "sites").

One consists of MultiPolygons (describing the broad frame of the site (`areas_sf`); the other consists of MultLine(Strings), which describes various physical features such as walls within the site (`lines_sf`). Both spatial layers use the same CRS system.

Each are loaded into R as sf objects using st_read(). Each site in the spatial layers has a unique identifying text/character column(s) by which they can theoretically be matched (i.e. merged or joined). I want to be able to combine all type of (simple) spatial features for each site into a single geometrycollection *per site*, so that affine transforms can be applied to them all. But I can't work out how to join both sets of features into a single geometry collection.

Normal `left_join()` using dplyr does not work since it does not like joining two sf objects. `st_join` is also not appropriate as it considers the spatial relations, not the fact that the relationship is already defined by text keys.

Since sf objects are data.frames with the geometry encapsulated in an assigned geometry column (`geom` or `geometry`), it seems like it should be possible to join the data.frames with included geometry column first, somehow combine (or union?) geometry.x and geometry.y in a row-wise way into GeometryCollection(s) and then transform back into single sf object. But how?

Presumably something like this (non-working) dplyr flow:-

```r
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

...

a1 <- areas_sf %>% as.data.frame()
l1 <- lines_sf %>% as.data.frame()

combined <- a1 %>% left_join(l1,by("id"="id")) %>%
   mutate(geometry_combined=st_geometrycollection(list(geometry.x,geometry.y))) %>%
   set_geometry("geometry_combined")
```

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `geometry_combined =
  st_geometrycollection(st_sfc(geometry.x, geometry.y))`.
Caused by error in `vapply()`:
! values must be length 3,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 2
```

It's probably something very obvious, I just can't work it out!

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth for those looking in future, `rowwise()` seems to achieve what I was looking for:-

```
a1 <- areas_sf %>% as.data.frame()
l1 <- lines_sf %>% as.data.frame()

combined <- a1 %>% left_join(l1,by("id"="id")) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(geometry = list(st_geometrycollection(c(geometry.x,geometry.y)))) %>%
  dplyr::select(-geometry.x,-geometry.y) %>%
  st_set_geometry("geometry") %>%
  st_set_crs(st_crs(areas_sf))
```